# Dynamic background color for groups of an expandablelistview not working

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

Iam trying to set a dynamic background for a group in a expandablelistview. So in my listviewAdapter I have the following code:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.elv_group, parent, false);
    }

    ((LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.elv_group_root_layout))
            .setBackgroundColor(getBackgroundColor(groupPosition));

    return convertView;
}

public int getBackgroundColor(int groupPosition) {
    if (getGroup(groupPosition).getInput().size() != getGroup(groupPosition).getOutput().size()) {
        return R.color.attention_row;
    } else {
        return R.color.normal_row;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I try to set the root layout background color depending on the given statement in the  method getBackgroundColor.

But all I get is a list of groups with always grey background! Can anyone tell me what Iam doing wrong here? Seems some kind of problem with the android list lifecycle or caching mechanism.
Is there a problem of changing the color of a linearLayout of a group in an expandablelistview? are the any other ways to highlight a specific group?

Comment: Are you sure getBackgroundColor ever returns the attention_row color?

Comment: yes, getBackgroundColor does return the right color (other then grey, which is displayed!)

Answer (score 1):

```
convertView.setBackgroundResource(getBackgroundColor(groupPosition));
```

instead of

```
((LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.elv_group_root_layout)).setBackgroundColor(getBackgroundColor(groupPosition));
```

saved my life ;)
thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070212/why-set-setbackgroundcolor-is-not-working-in-my-custom-listview)