# Android repeat array until it matches the adapter's count

Tags: android, arrays

I need your help. What I'm trying to do is to repeat the color array (blue, red, green) until it matches the adapter's count.

This is my sample:

```
public static final int[] colors = { R.color.main_blue, R.color.main_red, R.color.green_button };

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.verticalLine.setBackgroundColor(colors[position]);

}
```

But it will exceed the array since it only has 3 elements. (ArrayOutOfBoundsException) Any help to achieve this? I would gladly appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
holder.verticalLine.setBackgroundColor(colors[position%3]);
```

Use modulo 3 (you get the rest if you divide position by 3. For example 1%3 = 1, 5%3 = 2, 6%3 = 0

Comment: sorry this works when we change to setBackgroundResource since R.color is a resource

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Thanks to Jörn Buitink!

```
holder.verticalLine.setBackgroundResource(colors[position%3])
```

Change from BackgroundColor to BackgroundResource since R.color is a resource not a color.

You may also refer to this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070212/why-set-setbackgroundcolor-is-not-working-in-my-custom-listview)